# Have page slide in from right side ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm trying to add a transition where a user clicks on a button and the next page slides in from the right side.

Is that easy to do with the Ionic Framework?

I can't seem to find how to do that.

Here is what I have on my view:

```
<ion-view title="Payment" cache-view="false">
  <ion-content padding="false" class="has-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="spacer" style="width: 290px; height: 31px;"></div>
      <div class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
        <p style="color:#000000;">Payment Methods</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right">
        <i class="icon ion-card"></i>.... 2039
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="calm" ui-sref="paymentPage">Add Payment Method</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="spacer" style="width: 290px; height: 44px;"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this from official docs 
[slides component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/)

First disable swipe and then on button click you can call this function for transition

```
slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)
```